# How do I print out Ajax data according to the view page css?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I succeeded in importing data using Ajax (RestController) because I wanted to make the view page output different according to the selection option value.
But I'm not sure how to spread this data on the view page.
The code below is not through Ajax when the option value is total, but through the controller, I applied the entire serial list to the CSS and printed it out, and I want to output the data I brought through Ajax according to this css structure.

**partnerPlaceList.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp"%>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#guSelect').change(function(){
            var partner_place_address = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : '${PageContext.request.contextPath}/rental/location/'+partner_place_address,
                contentType : "application/json",
                data : {
                    location_gu : $(this).val()
                },
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function error(){
                     alert('error');
                }
            }); // ajax
            
        });
    });
    

</script>


<div class="container-xxl py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row g-5">

            <select class="form-select" style="height: 55px; width: 30%" id="guSelect" onchange="selectBoxChange(this.value);">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <c:forEach var="gu" items="${guList }">
                        <option value="${gu.location_gu_name }" 
                            <c:if test="${gu.location_gu_name == adminGu }">
                                selected
                            </c:if>
                        ><c:out value="${gu.location_gu_name }" /></option>
                    </c:forEach>
            </select>
            
                        
            <div class="row g-4">
                <c:forEach var="partnerPlace" items="${partnerPlaceList }">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s" onclick=" location.href='/rental/partnerPlaces/${partnerPlace.partner_place_no}'; " style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <div class="service-item rounded overflow-hidden" style="height: auto;">
                            <img src="${PageContext.requeset.contextPath }/resources/upload/partner_place/${partnerPlace.partner_place_image}" class="w-100 py-auto" style="height: 225px;">
                            <div class="position-relative p-4 pt-0">
                                <h4 class="mb-3 py-2">${partnerPlace.partner_place_name }</h4>
                                <div>
                                    <span>${partnerPlace.partner_place_address }</span>
                                    <div style="float: right;"><fmt:setLocale value="ko_KR"/><fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${partnerPlace.partner_place_price }" /><small> /hour</small></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>       
            
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    
    
    
<%@ include file="../include/footer.jsp"%>
```

**Controller**

```
    // http://localhost:8088/rental/partnerPlaceList
    @RequestMapping(value = "/partnerPlaceList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void placeListGet(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        log.info(" placeListGet() 호출 ");
        
        List<PartnerPlacesVo> partnerPlaceList = rentalService.getAllPartnerPlaceList();
        
        // addr - not detail
        for(PartnerPlacesVo vo :partnerPlaceList) {
            String[] addressArr = vo.getPartner_place_address().split(" ");
            String address = addressArr[0].substring(0, 2) + " " + addressArr[1];
            vo.setPartner_place_address(address);
        }
//      log.info("주소 자른 결과 : "+partnerPlaceList);
        model.addAttribute("partnerPlaceList", partnerPlaceList);
        
        // selectBox - (addr states?)list
        model.addAttribute("guList", rentalService.getBusanGuList());
        
        
    }
```

**RESTController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rental/*")
public class RentalRestController {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RentalRestController.class);
    
    @Inject
    private RentalService rentalService;
    
    //${PageContext.request.contextPath}/rental/location/'+partner_place_address
    @RequestMapping(value = "/location/{partner_place_address}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PartnerPlacesVo>> getCityPartnerPlaceREST(@PathVariable("partner_place_address") String partner_place_address){
        log.info(" getCityPartnerPlaceREST() 호출 ");
        log.info(partner_place_address);
        
        List<PartnerPlacesVo> cityPartnerPlaceList = rentalService.getCityPartnerPlaceList(partner_place_address);
        log.info(cityPartnerPlaceList+"");
        
        ResponseEntity<List<PartnerPlacesVo>> entity = null;
        
        try {
            entity = new ResponseEntity<List<PartnerPlacesVo>>(cityPartnerPlaceList, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entity = new ResponseEntity(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        
        log.info(entity+"");
        
        return entity;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Currently the only thing you're doing with the AJAX response is logging it to the console: `console.log(data);`  What else do you want to do with it?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: The console.log in the ajax success function was used to make sure that the data was imported well. First of all, I confirmed that I brought the data well through this. Now, I want to print this imported data to fit the HTML css as if it were just printed out through the controller at the bottom of the jsp code.

Comment: Then attempting to do that is your next step.  You are encouraged to write code to do that.  Writing that code will involve examining your client-side HTML and writing JavaScript code to update the DOM in that HTML.  If in your attempt you encounter a specific technical problem, this community can help with that.